# Pros and Cons of different audio transcoders

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, mplayer

I've been experimenting with different audio transcoders like ffmpeg, mplayer and LAME.

Does anyone have a qualitative comparison between the different audio transcoders that can be accessed through the terminal?

In my project I will be using these tools to do only two things

1. Transcode a 30 second clip of input.mp3 file to create output.wav
2. Crop a 30 second clip of input.mp3 to create output.mp3 WITHOUT transcoding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lame` is about the simplest without having to use a gui front end, as for cropping the resulting mp3 you can use `mp3splt` to split the mp3 into the part you want and the part you can discard without recoding:

```
lame file.wav file.mp3
```

The following chops file into 10 minute slices:

```
mp3splt -t 10.00 file.mp3
```

Comment: Sorry not on a linux machine at the moment but can lame go from .mp3 input to .wav output?

Comment: Answering my own comment above, yes you can but you can't change the audio sampling frequency when you decode to wave =(